# Recuperando imagens do banco de dados usando PHP + MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, imagem, arquivo

Eu preciso carregar imagens de um banco de dados MySql usando PHP, e depois colocar dentro de uma tag  no HTML, não estou conseguindo usando esse código:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","roberto","","");
$query = ("select imagem from FOTOS_PRODUTOS where id = 1");
$imagem = mysqli_query($con,$query);
$fetch = mysqli_fetch_object($imagem);
$primeira_imagem = $fetch[0];


//<!--PRODUTO TOP-->
print "<div class='products-top'>";
print "<div id='slider-top' class='carousel slide'>";
print "<div class='lista-prods carousel-inner' role='listbox'>";
print "<div class='item active'>";
print "<a href='#' title='Veja mais'>";
print "<span class='item-area'>";
print "<small class='nm-prod'>".$primeiro_descricao."</small>";
print "<strong class='preco'><small> ".$primeiro_parcelas." de </small> R$ ".$primeiro_valor_parcelas." </strong>";
print "<small class='parcelas'>ou R$ ".$primeiro_preco." a vista</small>";
print "</span>";
print "<img src='$primeira_imagem' alt='' />";
print "</a>";
print "</div>";
```

Comment: Pode postar seu codigo em HTML para que nossa analise seja completa?

Comment: Certo, editei a postagem

Comment: Qual é a extensão da imagem?

Answer (score -1):

Tente da seguinte forma:

```
$con = new mysqli("localhost","roberto","","");
$query = "select imagem from FOTOS_PRODUTOS where id = 1"; //não precisa de () aqui
$result = $con->query($query);
$imagem = $result->fetch_assoc();
$mime = "image/png"; //considerando que a imagem é um PNG, caso não seja altere para extensão da sua imagem
$primeira_imagem = 'data:' . $mime . ';base64,' . base64_encode($imagem['imagem']);

//<!--PRODUTO TOP-->
print "<div class='products-top'>";
print "<div id='slider-top' class='carousel slide'>";
print "<div class='lista-prods carousel-inner' role='listbox'>";
print "<div class='item active'>";
print "<a href='#' title='Veja mais'>";
print "<span class='item-area'>";
print "<small class='nm-prod'>".$primeiro_descricao."</small>";
print "<strong class='preco'><small> ".$primeiro_parcelas." de </small> R$ ".$primeiro_valor_parcelas." </strong>";
print "<small class='parcelas'>ou R$ ".$primeiro_preco." a vista</small>";
print "</span>";
print "<img src='$primeira_imagem' alt='' />";
print "</a>";
print "</div>";
```

Comment: Continua me retornando a imagem em formato binário, acredito que eu preciso converter esse resultado do select usando alguma função para o tipo imagem, porém não sei fazer isso.

Comment: Da forma que você colocou a pergunta dava entender que você consultava o caminho da imagem...vou alterar a resposta então...